# What are the Filemaker 10 script trigger events?

Tags: filemaker

I want to run a script when a field is changed and with script triggers I think it's possible. Bu I don't know how to.. Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your script.

In Edit Mode, right-click on a field and choose "Set Script Triggers..."

If you want the script to run when the field is changed, click the "OnObjectModify" event and then select your script.

Whenever the field is modified your script will now run.